# Security Concerns ODBC DSN - how well does DSN protect SQL Credentials?

Tags: sql-server, security, connectivity, odbc

ODBC DSN's have been around for a long time, yet SQL Server still supports them, which says a lot. But I'd like to know, given that this is an older technology, how well are the credentials protected?

I understand that System and User DSN's are stored in the registry, but it looks like these are only references with limited information.
(please keep in mind, it's not a question on whether to use DSN or not)
Thanks.

Comment: Normally, a DSN would not contain a password-- the user would need to provide a password at login time.  So I'm not sure what protection you're referring to.  Some ODBC drivers allow you to manually edit the registry to store a clear-text password for a DSN but that is generally not great for security.  You might be able to limit who can view that registry key through other security settings but that's getting further outside the apparent scope of your question.